# Use charindex to locate an apostrophe

Tags: sql-server, substring, where-clause, locate

I have data like this:

```
State   ID
-----   --
'CA'    5
'CA'    3
'MA'    2
'NH'    1
'NJ'    8
'NH'    9
```

For all the states it is putting apostrophes around the states.

I'm looking to somehow search by the state abbreviation but it won't let me search like this:

```
where state=''CA''
```

...because it's closing each apostrophe with the one after it.

I also tried this:

```
substring(state,charindex(''',state)+1),
    charindex(''',state)-charindex(''',state),+1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. I believe this is what you are wanting...

```
Where state like '''CA''%'
```

It is better to do it this way because you can use indexes. If you apply a function against the column, it must apply that against the entire table.

Comment: Doesn't bring back any results but I know it will have some